# Regex doesn't find a match

Tags: regex, perl, dictionary

I have a list which looks like this:

```
__DATA__
49103393193[0-9]{1,3};+49103/393193-0;Company 1;Street;Number;Postal Code;City
```

Now I load a big list with these values in to a Hash which looks like this:

```
%voicePrefix = (
  '49103393193[0-9]{1,3}' => [
                              '+49103/393193-0',
                              'Company 1',
                              'Street'
                              'Number'
                              'Postal Code'
                              'City'
                             ],
);
```

I do it by doing this:

```
my %voicePrefix = map {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split ';';
  shift @fields => \@fields;
} __DATA__;
my $voiceRegex = '(' . join('|',map{quotemeta} keys %voicePrefix) . ')';
```

Now the problem is I have another list with a lot of numbers so lets say I loaded a file in to @lines which looks like this:

```
__@lines__
4910339319344;Test 1
49103393193411;Test 2
49103393193941;Test 3
```

Now what I want to do is use the Regular Expression on the number I do it like this but it doesent work it never finds a Match

```
my @lines = __FILEUPTHERE__;
my @line;

my $company;

for(my $i = 0; i < @lines; $i++)
{
    #Split Line
    @line = split( /,/, $lines[$i] );

    #NO MATCH HERE
    $company = $voicePrefix{$1}[1] if ($line[0] =~ /$voiceRegex/);
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this Problem.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `quotemeta` when constructing the regex, which means that all of your hash keys will be treated literally in the regex.  You are looking for the literal string `49103393193[0-9]{1,3}`, instead of the number followed by 1-3 digits.

Remove the `map{quotemeta}` and you should be fine.

*Note: getting regexes from the input is a security hole if the input isn't coming from a trusted source.*

**Update:** Also, you almost never need C-style `for` loops in Perl.  They should be avoided.  Instead:

```
foreach my $line (@lines)
{
    #Declare a variable here if you are using it here.
    my @fields = split( /,/, $line );

    $company = $voicePrefix{$1}[1] if ($fields[0] =~ /$voiceRegex/);
}
```

**Update 2:** You also might want to add anchors to your regex, to ensure that you are matching the exact string, rather than a subset of a longer string: `/^$voiceRegex$/`.

**Update 3:** With these corrections, the match works.  However, you have an additional problem, in that you are trying to use the matched number as a key to `voicePrefix`.  However, that won't work, because the keys to voicePrefix are regexes, not numbers that might match such regexes.  A change in your design is needed.  The simplest way is to not create one big regex, but just test each key to see if one matches:

```
foreach my $line (@lines)
{
    #Declare a variable here if you are using it here.
    my @fields = split( /;/, $line );

    foreach my $regex (keys %voicePrefix)
    {
        $company = $voicePrefix{$regex}[1] if ($fields[0] =~ /$regex/);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it now with my $voiceRegex = '(' . join('|', keys %voicePrefix) . ')'; but it still doesent match

Comment: @alexj, there was another problem with your code as well.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you it works but isnt it possible to do it in one regex because your last solution slows my code my 6x it took 20seconds with one regex and like that it takes 120 seconds?

Comment: @alexj, yes you could do it in one regex.  You would have to rethink your design a little bit, though.  You have to think of the right way of keying your hash that will allow you to get the correct value.  It depends on your input data.  For example, do all of your regexes start with a unique 11-digit number?  If so you could use these 11 digits as the hash key, then use the first 11 characters of the match to get the value.